# Android DatePicker : How to set value from DatePicker in EditText in this format dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: android, android-datepicker

While setting a value in an `EditText` from a `DatePicker`, how do i set it as for ex 25-03-2014 instead of 25-3-2014.

Cos it displays 25-3-2014 with the missing '0' before the month(mm) everytime.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use mm in date format, it displays 03 as month or else if use m as month it displays 3. use your choice

Comment: inside the `DatePicker`?

Comment: Date format documentation: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/text/format/DateFormat.java.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edittext);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String date = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    if (date.contains("/")) {
        date = date.replace("/", "-");
    }
YourEditText.setText(date);
```

---

Add Click Event on YourEditText inside xml :

`android:onClick="onTime"`

Code Snippet:

Please extend your `Activity` from `FragmentActivity`

```
public void onTime(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new FromDatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "From Date");
}


    class FromDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yr = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mnth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yr, mnth, day); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String date;
        monthOfYear++;
        if (dayOfMonth < 10) {
            date = "0" + dayOfMonth + "-";
        } else {
            date = dayOfMonth + "-";
        }
        if (monthOfYear < 10) {
            date += "0" + monthOfYear + "-";
        } else {
            date += monthOfYear + "-";
        }

        date += year;
        YourEditText.setText(date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` class as "dd/MM/yyyy".

check the documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Below given code can solve you problem...

```
 DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
     dp.getDayOfMonth();
     dp.getMonth();
     dp.getYear();    
     if(dp.getMonth()+1<10)
         editText.setText(dp.getDayOfMonth()+"-"+"0"+(dp.getMonth() + 1 )+"-"+dp.getYear());
     if(dp.getDayOfMonth()<10)
         editText.setText("0"+dp.getDayOfMonth()+"-"+(dp.getMonth() + 1 )+"-"+dp.getYear() );
     if(dp.getMonth()+1<10 && dp.getDayOfMonth()<10)
         editText.setText("0"+dp.getDayOfMonth()+"-"+"0"+(dp.getMonth() + 1 )+"-"+dp.getYear() );
     if(dp.getMonth()+1>9 && dp.getDayOfMonth()>9)
         editText.setText( dp.getDayOfMonth()+"-"+(dp.getMonth() + 1 )+"-"+dp.getYear());

 dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make it like this,

```
final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
```